# search on custom field add in custom form in drupal

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

we have made a custom form for registration in drupal.
   where  we have add firstname,lastname,city,skills.
    Now we want to search user on these following criteria.
    But if when drupal made a new field, in backend it make a table with a field name.
    Eg:field_data_field_account_type

```
like we have writtern code for search on te basis of account type

   function getUsersList($type=null){
$query = db_select('users', 'u');
$query->join('field_data_field_account_type', 'at', 'u.uid = at.entity_id'); 
$query->fields('at')
->fields('u')
->condition('at.field_account_type_value',$type,'=')
->orderBy('created', 'DESC');

$result = $query->execute();
$users = array();
while($record = $result->fetchAssoc()) 
{
    $user_fields = user_load($record['uid']);
    $users[] = $user_fields;
}
return $users;
   }


but if we will search on multiple tables using joins search will become slow.
```

So, what approach we should follow to get name by firstname,city,skills,
 without using joins.

Is there any  form fields api function in drupal to  solve it.

I found one solution but here i m facing one problem .Here is my code

```
      i found some solution for my problem but i am facing one problem              

    $query = new EntityFieldQuery();
     $results=$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'user');
     if($type!=null)
     {
      $query->fieldCondition('field_account_type', 'value',$type, '=');
    }
           if($name!=null)
           {

 $query->fieldCondition('field_first_name', 'value',"%$name%", 'like');

//$query->fieldCondition('field_last_name', 'value',"%$name%", 'like');
           }

           /*if($city!=null&&isset($city))
           {
           $query->fieldCondition('field_city', 'value',"%$city%", 'like');
           }
            if($skill!=null&&isset($skill))
           {
    $query->fieldCondition('field_skills', 'value',"%$skill%", 'like');
            }*/
           $results->execute();


This code only work on first name , bu not for last name.lIKE here and condition is working for last name
```

so can i design  query like this using or in which only one textbox .seach user by firstname,lastname,city,skil etc.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I have to say is I know nothing about drupal, but I would suggest a different point of view.
your problem is that joining is really slow, so you'd like a non-join solution.

What I think instead is to improve the join speed instead of not using it, because I think "join" is a fairly reasonable thing to do under your situation.

to spped things up, I'd suggest adding index for uid in users table. Also entity_id & field_account_type_value in field_data_field_account_type.

having these 3 column indexed should massively increase your query speed if you haven't index it before.

Comment: i found some solution for my problem but i am facing one problem

Comment: sorry but i don't understand your comment at all. It's ok if my answer isn't working if you already have index.

Answer (score 0):

i doesn't get any solution so i copied the data of users in another table so tat searching become fast.

my code is :

```
function users_user_insert(&$edit, $account, $category) {
$coFounder      =   '';
 $founder       =   '';
 if($account->field_account_type['und'][0]['value']=='co-founder'){
$coFounder      =   $account->field_account_type['und'][0]['value'];
 }
 else if(($account->field_account_type['und'][0]['value']=='founder')&&($account-    
   >field_account_type['und'][1]['value']=='co-founder'))
  {
$founder        =   $account->field_account_type['und'][0]['value'];
$coFounder      =   $account->field_account_type['und'][1]['value'];
 }
 else{
$founder        =   $account->field_account_type['und'][0]['value'];
  }


   $result = db_insert('lew_users_meta')->fields(array('uid'=>$account-    
   >uid,'name'=>$account->name,'first_name'=>$account->field_first_name['und'][0]
   ['value'],
'last_name'=>$account->field_last_name['und'][0]['value'],'mail'=>$account->mail,
'city'=>$account->field_city['und'][0]['value'],
     'skills'=>$account->field_skills['und'][0]['value'],


          'coFounder'=>$coFounder,'founder'=>$founder,'created'=>time()
                        )


                       )                 
                       ->execute();

         }

     function users_user_update(&$edit, $account, $category) {
     $coFounder     =   '';
     $founder       =   '';
    if($account->field_account_type['und'][0]['value']=='co-founder'){
$coFounder      =   $account->field_account_type['und'][0]['value'];
     }
 else if(($account->field_account_type['und'][0]['value']=='founder')&&($account-   
  >field_account_type['und'][1]['value']=='co-founder'))
 {
$founder        =   $account->field_account_type['und'][0]['value'];
$coFounder      =   $account->field_account_type['und'][1]['value'];
 }
 else{
$founder        =   $account->field_account_type['und'][0]['value'];
  }

    $result = db_update(' lew_users_meta')
                       ->fields(array('name'=>$account->name,'first_name'=>$account-    
      >field_first_name['und']['0']['value'],
'last_name'=>$account-     
    >field_last_name['und'][0]['value'],'mail'=>$account->mail,
'city'=>$account->field_city['und'][0]['value'],
    'skills'=>$account->field_skills['und']['0']['value'],

      'founder'=>$founder,'coFounder'=>$coFounder,'modified'=>time()
                        )


                       )
                       ->condition('uid', $account->uid,'=')
                       ->execute();



  }
```

so we have used hook to insert data in another table.so that we should not joins the
    table.

if you have better solution please post here